Conformal Antenna Behavior on Metal Body vs Composite Body
I am looking at a conformal antenna such as this from L3 Harris. How would the antenna behavior be different if this was mounted on a vehicle that was fully made of metal like aluminum vs a vehicle made fully of composite. I am not looking for a detailed radiation pattern as I realize that would require more information and likely a simulation, but in generality would one material type be better than the other for antenna (receive and transmit) performance?
EDIT: Adding for more comments as requested. The antenna would be mounted on the fuselage (near the front) of an aerospace vehicle. The frequency bands would be C, S, and X band. I am trying to understand the impact a metal vs composite fuselage would have on the antenna behavior. Again, I am not asking for detail radiation pattern rather I am interested in the fundamental principles to help understand the impact.

A much more detailed technical requirements specification for the linked antenna is needed.

It's totally useless to ask here. Conformal antenna must be designed for a certain surface to make the phase shifts right for each element. Conformal antenna supplier designs the antenna for the customer according the specs including the surrounding surface material. You cannot buy a big rubber plate antenna which adapts easily to any surface form when it's assembled by inserting the feed coaxial and rubber cement. In theory every element could have own adjustable feeding circuit which could be calibrated for different surface forms&materials, but the cost would be in the military radar league

If you improve your question by specifying the vehicle, the proposed mounting location, and the frequency, you might get some better advice.

Please let me know if the edit helps

In general some antennas use the ground as reference plane and a "mirror".  Not going into too much details, i'll give a simple example. If you have a monopole antena (just a piece of wire of certain length) and no ground around it really acts like monopole antena. If you put it over infinite ground plane, it becomes a dipole antenna with wavelengths double the previous antena (freq/2) as the rf currents in the ground plane are just the opposite as the ones in the antenna. You can imagine this as an another virtual monopole underneath the ground plane, which creates a dipole with total length double to your real antenna -"real" antenna and  the "mirror" antenna. You can read about it here: https://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/monopole.php
This is important concept to understand as ground is important for antenna operation.
In general the antenna you shared already includes its ground plane.  the fact that it has its own gnd means you can put it on plastic or metal and it will act in a similar way. Had it not have the gnd it would either need to be placed near gnd or would need not to be, depending on the type (see above example) in order to get desired performance.
For your example however, as said no need to think about this. In general the better the ground the better the performance in terms of efficiency, matching, etc.
what you need to be aware of is that radiation pattern can change, usually it becomes more narrow with more ground area added. Not always. And you don't always want this, since someone applications want wide radiation patterns (low directivity).
You will have to try this, one way or another, with the exact antenna you are planning on using. The design of the actual antenna will make the antenna respond differently to ground plane.
You have a couple of options, there are loads of simulators available, or you can flget a sample of the antenna and mount it on whatever material you are planning to use, try to use similar shape ant at leas the area of 2x wavelength or size of a final product (whatever is smaller) and measure the radiation pattern, efficiency, matching etc.

I can give you a general answer, but see the caveat below.
From the datasheet -- which seems intentionally vague -- the antenna appears to consist of an array of elements. It's likely either the elements include their own reflectors, or the whole assembly has a reflective base surface. In either case, the conductivity of the mounting surface under the antenna would be of little consequence, and there is no clear advantage to mounting the antenna on a metal vs composite vehicle.
If the array is steerable and designed to "look" at angles nearly parallel to the plane of the mounting surface, however, a metal vs composite vehicle mounting may have some effect on the radiation pattern, mainly the sidelobes. However, since the antenna appears to be a custom design, there's the potential to compensate for this.
Caveat: the antenna you're considering is a sophisticated and costly military-grade antenna, so hopefully you won't be making major design decisions based only on advice from SE!

right it does have its own reflectors so would the metal skin fuselage vs composite skin fuselage around it have any influence on antenna performance?

The datasheet is about a class of antennas which can claim to be conformal, i.e. not sticking out at all, by being built into the composite structure of a replacement compatible aircraft part.
The antenna elements of the array look like they are fully formed antennas with their own ground plane or reflector or whatever.
They're not conformal as in stick-onto-the-existing-surface, they're actually just embedded in the structure. So they're not directly affected by the existing ground plane.
If the part that's replaced was always composite, then the antennas will include their own ground, or rely on the aircraft skin behind them. If it was metal part, then the replacement will may be partially composite, or have holes in the metal, covered by a thin radome etc.

I am not sure I understand, are you that metal vs composite skin fuselage have no impact on the antenna radiation pattern?

No I'm saying that (in this brochure) L3 are offering replacement panels for aircraft that have antennas built in. They can control the effect of the skin because they made it. So the question of metal or composite is moot. Conformal antennas always require some cooperation from the structure. A pure metal skin needs a very different antenna to a pure composite skin. Also there are always wires and other metal behind the skin, so the whole aircraft needs to be taken into account.

Ok, so is one "easier" to work with than another? For conformal antennas is a metal skin preferred  because it is conductive vs composite?

It depends... But if it sticks onto an existing metal skin, then it's just a low profile Antenna, not a Conformal Antenna. A truly flat antenna is only possible on/in a non-conductive surface. Just semantics really.

I don't follow, I guess to put it another way will there be no difference in antenna performance if it was surrounded by a conductive metal skin that can act as ground than a composite skin?
